# Tornado server on Heroku. Error R10 (Boot Timeout)

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, procfile

I am trying to deploy a web app that I wrote in Python using tornado server.

In my `app.py` I have

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(Application())
    server.listen(4200, address='0.0.0.0')
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I then have a Procfile that has `web: python app.py`

When I check the logs I see the error

```
2018-08-08T02:20:54.117821+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python app.py`
2018-08-08T02:20:57.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-08-08T02:21:54.891301+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2018-08-08T02:21:54.891301+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2018-08-08T02:21:55.027586+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2018-08-08T02:21:55.049407+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-08-08T02:21:55.051776+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-08-08T02:21:59.562357+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python app.py`
```

I don't know too much of what I'm doing, especially with the `Procfile` so I'm guessing the issue lies there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku [tells you which port you should bind to via the `PORT` environment variable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/runtime-principles#web-servers). You should use that instead of hard-coding a port, e.g.

```
import os

port = int(os.getenv('PORT', 4200))
server.listen(port, address='0.0.0.0')
```

This will use the `PORT` environment variable if it is present (e.g. on Heroku) and fall back to 4200 if it isn't (e.g. on your development machine).